# How to round Google Maps Duration and Distance calculator

Tags: javascript, rounding

I have a small distance and duration calculator and I'm wondering how I would go about rounding up/down my final figures so for example, instead of a final duration of 7.433333333333334 mins or a final distance of 3.604 KMs. I'd get 7 minutes and 4 Kms.

Here is my current code:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
  <title>Distance Calculator</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
   #map_canvas { 
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
   }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var directionDisplay;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var map;
  
  


  function initialize() {
   directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
   var perth = new google.maps.LatLng(-31.949766, 115.860928);
   var myOptions = {
    zoom:12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: perth
   }

   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
   directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  }

  function calcRoute() {
   var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
   var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
   var distanceInput = document.getElementById("distance");
   var durationInput = document.getElementById("duration");
   
   
   var request = {
    origin:start, 
    destination:end,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
   };
   
   directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
     directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
     distanceInput.value = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000;
     durationInput.value = response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value / 60;
     }
   });
  }
  
  function updateDue() {

    var total = parseInt(document.getElementById("odoend").value);
    var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("odostart").value);
    var val3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("distance").value);

    // to make sure that they are numbers
    if (!total) { total = 0; }
    if (!val2) { val2 = 0; }
    if (!val3) { val3 = 0; }

    var ansD = document.getElementById("kmused");
    ansD.value = total - val2;
   
    var ansE = document.getElementById("kmpriv");
    ansE.value = ansD.value - val3;
}
  </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="initialize()">
  <div>
   <p>
    <label for="start">Enter your current clients address:</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="start" id="start" />
    <p>
    <label for="end">Enter your next clients address: </label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="end" id="end" />
    <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Calculate Route" onclick="calcRoute()" />
    </p>
    <label for="odostart">Enter start odometer reading: </label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="odostart" id="odostart" onchange="updateDue()">
    <p>
    <label for="odoend">Enter end odometer reading: </label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="odoend" id="odoend" onchange="updateDue()">
    <p>
     <label for="kmused">Total KMs used</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="kmused" id="kmused">
    <p>
    <label for="kmpriv">Private KMs used</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="kmpriv" id="kmpriv">
    <p>
 
    <p>
    <label for="distance">Distance to next client (km): </label><br>
    <input type="text" name="distance" id="distance" onchange="updateDue()" />
    <p>
    <label for="duration">Duration to next client (min): </label><br>
    <input type="text" name="duration" id="duration" onchange="updateDue()" />
   </p>
   
  </div>
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the `Math.round()` function.

Comment: @Hsan You would call `Math.round(insert_time_var_here)` and use that in place of `insert_time_var_here` in the function. Do you understand what I am saying?

Comment: tried this to no avail
 var durationInput = Math.round(document.getElementById("duration"));

also math.round("durationInput");

Comment: The `Math.round()` does not round the argument, but returns a rounded copy of the argument. You would have to place the `response.route.../...` in `calcRoute()` *between* the parentheses of `Math.round()` and **keep** the rest of the line.

Comment: THANK YOU! it was very simple in hindsight.

Comment: @Hsan I am glad I could help. :)